# TYPO3 config.linkVars gets cached

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x

I'm just wondering about the behavior of `config.linkVars = test(0-100)`.

My expectation was that all links generated with Typolink will now add the current value of the GET var - lets say &test=66 - to all links of the page. That basically works, but TYPO3 will cache the whole site for all users now even if they have this GET param or not. So every user receive all links containing &test=66 even if they dont have the GET param in their or URL or another value of this GET var.

I though TYPO3 should generate a new cache for each possible value of the config.linkVar?

Tested with and without realUrl and with and without `[FE][cHashExcludedParameters] = test` in the install tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different cache spaces are by default generated for each typoscript-condition.
As long as you have no specific condition no cache space is generated and all generated content is stored in one space. Independent of individual setting of `test` with first value of test.

as your range for test is very wide you might need to insert a big block of conditions into your TS

```
[globalVar GP:test = 1]
[globalVar GP:test = 2]
[globalVar GP:test = 3]
[globalVar GP:test = 4]
[globalVar GP:test = 5]
  :
[globalVar GP:test = 99]
[globalVar GP:test = 100]
[global]
```

If you only need some single values try to define it

```
config.linkVars = test(0,14-16,38,66,100)
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Fortunately I've only got one parameter with one possible value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there maybe now a less "hackish" solution for this? That workaround only works when the values are known.